# Facebook API non embeddable videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Facebook videos that aren't embeddable from their pages still say they are when accessed via the Graph API.

E.g. https://www.facebook.com/nba/videos/10154208341578463/ won't allow an embed (from the top right hand corner drop down arrow)

but when using the [Graph Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10154208341578463%2F%3Ffields%3Dembeddable%2Clength%2Cprivacy%2Cstatus%2Clive_status%2Cpermalink_url%2Cis_instagram_eligible%2Cembed_html&version=v2.2), on the same item, the JSON returned is thus:

```
{
  "embeddable": true,
  "length": 13.779,
  "privacy": {
    "allow": "",
    "deny": "",
    "description": "Public",
    "friends": "",
    "networks": "",
    "value": "EVERYONE"
  },
  "status": {
    "video_status": "ready"
  },
  "permalink_url": "/nba/videos/10154208341578463/",
  "is_instagram_eligible": false,
  "embed_html": "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10154208341578463\" width=\"400\" height=\"224\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",
  "updated_time": "2016-07-25T00:56:09+0000",
  "id": "10154208341578463"
}
```

Where you can see that the API fields for `embeddable` is `true` and all other fields returned suggest the video can be embedded.

The reason this is causing headaches is that when pulling in a user's items from their feed there is no way to tell which videos can be shown or not, until they are embedded and attempted to be played, which results in the following:

[image]

Has anyone else come across this problem? Is there another Graph endpoint I can hit to get the correct embeddable video info?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that `embeddable` property refers to the `embed_html` – you can embed the video using that iframe code. It does not seem to refer to the Embedded Video Player social plugin.

Comment: @CBroe Facebook suggests not to use said embed_html property. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player#faq for various reasons.

Comment: I didn’t say you should use it; I just explained that apparently this way of embedding is what the `embeddable` property refers to. Would perhaps make sense to file a bug report, and ask if they would consider to either change what that property refers to, or add an additional property that allows to check if the video can be embedded using the plugin. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @CBroe Apologies, I misunderstood your comment. I'll send off a bug report and see what comes back. Cheers!